# Connecting to database from Custom Cursor Adapter Class

Tags: java, android

I am having some issues calling a method in my database class from my cursor adapter class. The custom cursor class is being used to get the row_id of a row where a checkbox has been ticked. I have retired the row_id fine, my problem is calling to the database to delete that row.

I am calling to the database in a way that I know that works as I have used it in other activities. The error is also a null pointer error. I know what a null pointer error is but I cannot seem to figure out why I am getting one here.

The error only occurs when the delete method is in the `onCheckChanged`, if I hard code the row_id into the function in say the `bindView` function everyhting works fine. Is it possible to pass a Context into the `onCLickChanged` function?

Does the fact that the activity doesnt extend Activity make a difference?

**Initializing DB Class and context**

```
private static Context context;
DBMain db = new DBMain(context);
```

**onCheckedChange Method**

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    int id = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

    db.deleteItem(id);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Row " + id + " Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

 }
}
```

**Database Class**

```
    public boolean deleteItem(int id)
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(SHOPPING_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=\"" + id + "\"", null) > 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: what does id show as when your deleteItem function is called? I also believe you don't require the escaping characters in your query.

Comment: does your class extexds Activity and why are you passing a null context ?

Comment: No the activity extends SImpleCursorAdapter, I did have it equal to `this` but in doing so I got an error saying `Error:(27, 31) error: incompatible types: ShoppingCustomAdapter cannot be converted to Context`

Comment: I think it is better to create a custom adapter class different from your Activity class. You can as well make the custom adapter class an inner class of the activity if you will only use it once.

Comment: So just create the custom cursor adapter inside the activity that is calling it? and then ill be able to call the context?

Comment: @NollyJ that seemed to do the trick thanks very much

Comment: @JJSmith, glad it helped you. Please upvote my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move  private static Context context;
    to private static Context context = this ;

Comment: I already tried this and got the following error `Error:(27, 31) error: incompatible types: ShoppingCustomAdapter cannot be converted to Context`

Comment: try this one final DBMain db = new db(getActivity());